# Parent property of ITestSuiteBase always returns null

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

We have an requirement where we are using TFS & MTM SDK we need to retrieve the test suites information.
As part of the requirement I will get the test suite id and using this I should be able to retrieve corresponding parent test suites till I reach the top. My sample code is snippet is shown below

```
ITestSuiteBase testSuite = teamProject.TestSuites.Find(suiteId);
            List<TFSItem> suiteList = new List<TFSItem>();

            if (testSuite != null)
            {
                // this is the test plan
                if (testSuite.Parent == null)
                {
                    suiteList.Add(new TFSItem(testSuite.Id.ToString(), testSuite.Title));
                }
                else
                {
                    var tempSuite = testSuite;
                    while (tempSuite.Parent != null)
                    {
                        suiteList.Add(new TFSItem(tempSuite.Id.ToString(), tempSuite.Title));
                        tempSuite = tempSuite.Parent;
                    }

                    suiteList.Add(new TFSItem(tempSuite.Id.ToString(), tempSuite.Title));
                }
            }
```

Here irrespective of the test suite type (dynamictestsuite or statictestsuite), the parent is always returning null.

Can anyone please let me know am I missing something here? 
If there is any other alternative solution please let me know.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Is this testsuit is the root suit? Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestsuitebase.parent(v=vs.110)

Comment: I have already gone through this and after going through this started using Parent property in my code. But no luck this property is always returning me null.